# How to stop clearQueue() from clearing in-future queues?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, queue

I have a button, upon clicking on which a div is shown in 500ms and then after 500ms class shake is added onto that div. This shake classe is then removed after 2 seconds with `delay`. What I want is if user keep pressing on button then all callbacks become canceled except the last one.

Problematic code if click is pressed many time:

```js
$("button").click(function() {
  $(".content").show({
    duration: 500,
    done: function() {
      $(".content").addClass("shake");
      var time = parseFloat($(".content").css("transition-duration")) * 1000;
     
      $(".content").delay(time).queue(function() {
        console.log("shake");
        $(".content").removeClass("shake");
        $(".content").dequeue();
      });
    }
  })
});
```

```css
div.content {
  border: 1px solid red;
  transition: background-color 2s ease-out;
  background-color: black;
  display: none;
}

div.content.shake {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>click</button>
<div class="content">Content</div>
```

My solution with clearQueue:

```js
$("button").click(function() {
  $(".content").show({
    duration: 500,
    done: function() {
      $(".content").clearQueue();
      $(".content").addClass("shake");
      var time = parseFloat($(".content").css("transition-duration")) * 1000;
     
      $(".content").delay(time).queue(function() {
        console.log("shake");
        $(".content").removeClass("shake");
        $(".content").dequeue();
      });
    }
  })
});
```

```css
div.content {
  border: 1px solid red;
  transition: background-color 2s ease-out;
  background-color: black;
  display: none;
}

div.content.shake {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>click</button>
<div class="content">Content</div>
```

But this method never lets the `shake` class to be added. Because the queue mentioned after `clearQueue` is also cleared.

How can I prevent clearQueue() from clearing in-future queues? And why does `clearQueue()` behave this way? How does it know what `queue` would be added in future?

Comment: Do you have to use `.queue()` for this? It seems there are better alternatives to get the effect you want.

Comment: Can you use use `setTimeout` instead of `.delay()`?

Comment: @jbe Yes, on my live site I fixed the issue with `setTimout`. But I want to understand how `clearQueue()` works.

Comment: As a side note, you could use debounce on the function to avoid the effects of the nervous user

Answer (score 2):

Provide a name for the `.delay()` and `.queue()` calls. Check if `.content` `.queue(queueName)` has a `.length` before setting `.delay(time, queueName)`. Chain `.dequeue(queueName)` to `.queue(queueName)` call instead of calling `.dequeue()` within `.queue()` function. Note that `.delay()` also adds a function to element `.queue()` array

```js
$("button").click(function() {
  $(".content").show({
    duration: 500,
    done: function() {
      $(".content").clearQueue();
      $(".content").addClass("shake");
      var time = parseFloat($(".content").css("transition-duration")) * 1000;
      if (!$(".content").queue("shake").length)
      $(".content").delay(time, "shake").queue("shake", function() {
        console.log("shake");
        $(".content").removeClass("shake");
      }).dequeue("shake");
    }
  })
});
```

```css
div.content {
  border: 1px solid red;
  transition: background-color 2s ease-out;
  background-color: black;
  display: none;
}

div.content.shake {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>click</button>
<div class="content">Content</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Note: this solution uses a different method than `clearQueue()`.

As mentioned in the comments, there might be better options for achieving the effect you want. It sounds like you're trying to keep the `shake` class enabled for X seconds after the last button press.

We can accomplish this with `setTimeout()`, which executes a function after a specified amount of time. In this cause, we'll have our `setTimeout()` callback function remove the `.shake` class after `time` seconds.

To keep the `.shake` class enabled when the button is clicked we only need to 'reset' the `setTimeout` function. We can do this by clearing the timeout, using `clearTimeout`, then recreating it. This is accomplished by assigning the `setTimeout` function to a variable, which we pass to `clearTimeout` to clear it, then recreate the timeout.

The effect will be that the function to remove the `.shake` class will run `time` seconds AFTER the last time the button is clicked.

```js
var remover;

$("button").click(function() {
  $(".content").show({
    duration: 500,
    done: function() {
      if (remover) {
          clearTimeout(remover);
      }
      
      $(".content").addClass("shake");
      var time = parseFloat($(".content").css("transition-duration")) * 1000;
 
      remover = window.setTimeout(function(){
        console.log("removing shake");
        $(".content").removeClass("shake");
      }, time)
    }
  })
});
```

```css
div.content {
  border: 1px solid red;
  transition: background-color 2s ease-out;
  background-color: black;
  display: none;
}

div.content.shake {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>click</button>
<div class="content">Content</div>
```

Comment: Hi Brett, thanx for your response. In my website I used quite similar solution. I just didn't have the `if(remover)` at the beginning. Rest is same approach. Could you also explain why my method with `clearQueue()` didn't work?

Comment: Not entirely sure, but I think it might, in part, be due to the chaining of `$('.content').delay().queue()`. I believe the `delay()` should be inside the callback function. That said, I think `setTimeout` is still a better route to go.

Comment: I'm also not sure `.queue` is intended for this purpose. It might be possible, but again, I think there are alternatives that are more elegant, and easier to understand.